# React Native splash screen generator your binary is not optimized for iphone 5

Tags: ios, react-native, splash-screen

[http://apetools.webprofusion.com/tools/imagegorilla](http://apetools.webprofusion.com/tools/imagegorilla%20%20https://makeappicon.com/%20%20http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/)
[http://ticons.fokkezb.nl](http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/)

I make splash screen production on the two sites I mentioned above. Working on the phone and in the emulator. When I archive and store the application I get the following error

[image: your binary is not optimized for iphone 5]

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you should make launch screen with storyboard and not with static images. From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/) on launch screens:

> Because device screen sizes vary, launch screen sizes vary too. To
>   accommodate this, you can provide a launch screen as an Xcode
>   storyboard or as a set of static images for the devices your app
>   supports. Using an Xcode storyboard is the recommended approach, as
>   storyboards are flexible and adaptable. You can use a single
>   storyboard to manage all of your launch screens.

So real solution for this problem is to do your launch screen with storyboards :)

Comment: I tried it again and again. He accepted. But I still do not understand why

Comment: He? Steve Jobs or who? :D Can you explain more?